# Windows Explorer Does Not Include Hidden Files' Size When Calculating Folder Size

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, powershell

It seems Windows Explorer does not include the sizes of "hidden" files when calculating the parent folder size, even when I check "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" in the "Folder and Search Options". When I hide a folder, Explorer reports it as empty when I mouse over it, even when there are files &/or folders in it. A similar issue arises with "Operating System Files and Folders", or files hidden and often inaccessible to the average user that control how Windows operates and are very dangerous to mess with.

Why does this happen? Also, is there a way for Explorer to include these files/folders when calculating the parent folder's size? Perhaps including other users' files/folders, even if you can't access them? Even for files you are not allowed to access, knowing the size of the folder seems important.

For me, this is happening in Windows 8, but I wouldn't be surprised if other Windows versions did the same thing.

I would like the solution to work right in Windows Explorer, but any solutions, including ones scripting languages, is fine.

Comment: You realize that PowerShell is simply the command line interface for a scripting language right?

Comment: I fail to see your point. You can do shell scripting with the "scripting language used by the CLI that is PowerShell", and I don't know what this scripting language is, if it even has a name.

Comment: The name is powershell. All a powershell script is is the same commands you would do at the CLI put into a text file. So when you do those commands at the CLI you are using a scripting language. So saying that you won't entertain scripting language answers seems like a silly limitation.

Comment: I meant I'll accept the 2 scripting languages built into Windows, just not whatever things like Python, Perl, etc. are. Sorry for the confusion. I just put I'll accept scripting languages in general so it's easier.

Comment: There are at least three scripting languages built into windows since at least windows 7.

Comment: Do people usually put solutions involving scripting in SuperUser? If so I'll just take that part out.

Comment: Oh, what's the 3rd?

Comment: Since W7 Batch, Powershell, and VBScript have all been built in. And yes scripting questions are perfectly valid here as long as they are something that a super user might want to do. Which this is.

Comment: OK, then I guess I'll just take that part out, thanks.

Comment: Is batch just the cmd.exe prompt?

Comment: A scripting language is simply a set of commands that are stored in a text file that is read and executed by an interpreter. The commands that you type in the cmd.exe prompt are executed by the same interpreter yes.

Comment: So, which Windows version are we talking about?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Windows 8, but I assumed if Windows 8 does it, pretty much all do. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution in Powershell. You can tweak it all that you want:

```
(Get-ChildItem .\* -force | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Length | Measure-Object -Sum).sum
```

Comment: this script doesn't work for me. "Length" property not found.

Comment: I would rather have a solution only involving Windows Explorer, but since this is the only answer so far, I have accepted it for now.

Comment: @magicandre1981 which version of powershell?

Comment: I use Powershell version which is part of Windows 8(.0).

Comment: Woops. had a typo. corrected now

Comment: You didn't explain why this happened, @EBGreen. (not sure if there's really a reason other than "Microsoft wanted it to)

Comment: Oh, I have no idea why explorer works that way. I'm odd though...If you can't do it at the command prompt it probably isn't worth doing. :)

Comment: You know, I'm starting to think that way, myself. But GUI's are good for organizing information, if they're good GUI's. Also, you have to type a lot in the command prompt to do some things a single button press will do in a GUI (sometimes). Especially in PowerShell.